# ¿Cómo hacer referencia a la función de un objeto desde HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, botón, entrada

estoy empezando con HTML y Javascript y pretendo recoger el valor del text input con id "login" y mostrarlo cuando pulse el boton "login" y no me aparece nada, creo que no me reconoce el javascript. Este es el HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>login</title>
    <script> 
        window.resizeTo(700,900); 
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="app">

      <table id=tabla style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th> <input type="text" class="input" id="login" placeholder="Su API_KEY de Trello"/> </th>    
            <div id="txt"></div>

          </tr>
           <tr>
               <th> <form action="https://trello.com/app-key/">
                    <input type="submit" class="nobutton"value="Consiga su API_KEY aquí"/> 
                    </form>
          </th> 
           </tr>
          <tr>   

        <th>         
              <input type="button" name="button"class="button" value="Login"onclick ="myfuncion()"/>
            <p id="demo">hola</p>
               </th>   
        </tr>
        </table>        

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Este es el index.js

```
        var app = {
        // Application Constructor
        initialize: function() {
            this.bindEvents();
        },
        // Bind Event Listeners
        //
        // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
        // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
        bindEvents: function() {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
        },
        // deviceready Event Handler
        //
        // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
        // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
        onDeviceReady: function() {
            app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        },
        // Update DOM on a Received Event
        receivedEvent: function(id) {
            var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
            var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
            var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

            listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
            receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

            console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
        }



    function myfuncion() {
       var x = document.getElementById("login").value;
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }

};
```

Comment: Tu problema es que has puesto en tu botón la función `myfuncion()` y en tu Javascript tienes `myFunction()`. Tendrían que llamarse de la misma manera.

Comment: Me equivoque al poner aqui el index.js, ese no es mi problema, lo tengo así y sigue sin fucnionar

Comment: ¿Te da algún error en la consola del navegador?

Comment: No, no tengo ningun error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmente tu problema es que tienes tu función englobada dentro del scope de un objeto, por lo que tendrás que referenciar dicho objeto también desde el HTML.

```
<input type="button" name="button"class="button" value="Login"onclick ="app.myfuncion()"/>
                                                                         ^
```

Además, tienes mal definida la función dentro del objeto. Debería ser de la forma:

```
nombre_de_la_funcion : function(){
   //Código
}
```

Tu ejemplo corregido:

```js
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    },

    myfuncion: function() {
      var x = document.getElementById("login").value;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }
};
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <table id=tabla style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th> <input type="text" class="input" id="login" placeholder="Su API_KEY de Trello"/> </th>    
        <div id="txt"></div>

      </tr>
       <tr>
           <th> <form action="https://trello.com/app-key/">
                <input type="submit" class="nobutton"value="Consiga su API_KEY aquí"/> 
                </form>
      </th> 
       </tr>
      <tr>   

    <th>         
          <input type="button" name="button"class="button" value="Login"onclick ="app.myfuncion()"/>
        <p id="demo">hola</p>
           </th>   
    </tr>
    </table>        
</div>
```

Comment: Ya había probado antes así, muchas gracias, pero probé el nuevo código y sigue sin mostrarme nada al clickar en el botón :s

Comment: @Silvia ¿Te da algún error en la consola? Ten en cuenta también que tiene que haber una `,` entre funciones. ¿La has indicado?

Comment: la , esta, ahora he visto que  me avisa de que "document. is not defined"

Comment: La , esta puesta, ahora veo que me da un error "document. is not defined"

Comment: @Silvia Engloba todo el objeto dentro de `window.onload = function() { //Aquí el objeto };`. De esta manera, hasta que el HTML no esté cargado, el Javascript no se ejecutará.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias ya lo he solucionado, con tanta prueba me había cargado parte del HTML